# Nuget equivalent to npm install --save-dev

Tags: .net, nuget

I am developing a Class Library for Dynamics (D365) plugins, and so I'm constrained to not add dependency assemblies in order to deploy/register it.

The case in particular, I'm interested in using the Sonar Lint nugget package and some rules to make the code look more homogeneous, I'm afraid that in doing so I'd be adding a dependency and won't be able to deploy/register after that.

I have used `npm install --save-dev {package}` to install linters and other dev-only dependencies and tools.

Is there a way to install a nuget package for development only?

**Disclaimer:** I know I can IL-merge to deploy/register external dependencies into D365 but that's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the [`PackageReference` style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999) of referencing NuGet packages, you can exclude assets from deployment or downstream inclusion (referencing libraries, packages) by setting `PrivateAssets`:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Nerdbank.GitVersioning" Version="3.5.119" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>
```